# Rewrite a variable in terms of another variable

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, replacement, algebraic-manipulation

I have two variables

```
  t = 1/Sqrt[2] (Sqrt[1 + Cos[a]] + Sqrt[1 - Cos[a]] + 
  Sqrt[1 + Cos[b]] + Sqrt[1 - Cos[b]] + Sqrt[1 + Cos[c]] + 
  Sqrt[1 - Cos[c]])
```

and

```
p = 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3 + 2 (Cos[a] + Cos[b] + Cos[c])]/3)
```

I need to write `p` in terms of `t`. How do I do it?

EDIT

```
p[a_, b_, c_] := 
 Sqrt[3 + 2 (Cos[a] + Cos[b] + Cos[c])] - 
  Sqrt[3 + 2 (Cos[a] - Cos[b] - Cos[c])] + 
  Sqrt[3 + 2 (-Cos[a] - Cos[b] + Cos[c])] - 
  Sqrt[3 + 2 (-Cos[a] + Cos[b] - Cos[c])]; 
t[a_, b_, c_] := 
 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3 + 2 (Cos[a] + Cos[b] + Cos[c])]/3); 
g = {};

n = 1; 
While[n < 10000, a = RandomReal[{0, Pi/2}]; 
 b = RandomReal[{0, Pi/2}];
 c = RandomReal[{0, Pi/2}]; 
 pra = p[a, b, c]; 
 tra = t[a, b, c];
 AppendTo[g, {pra, tra}]; n++]; 
ListPlot[g]
```

I have redefined the functions `p` and `t`. Now, I need to impose an additional constraint on `c`; that it falls between `Abs[a - b]` and  `a + b`. How do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You have 2 functions of 3 variables: t[a,b,c] and p[a,b,c].  In general, you can not write t in terms of only t: p[t]. 
However, what you may try to do is to write p in terms of e.g. t,b,c:  p[t,b,c]. But note that this will change the definition region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
p = 1/Sqrt[2] (Sqrt[1 + Cos[a]] + Sqrt[1 - Cos[a]] + 
     Sqrt[1 + Cos[b]] + Sqrt[1 - Cos[b]] + Sqrt[1 + Cos[c]] + 
     Sqrt[1 - Cos[c]]);

t = 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3 + 2 (Cos[a] + Cos[b] + Cos[c])]/3);
```

We assign random values to the 3 variables `a`, `b` and `c`

```
val := Block[{a = RandomReal[{0, 2 π}], 
   b = RandomReal[{0, 2 π}], c = RandomReal[{0, 2 π}]}, {p, t}]
```

Examining a plot of these

```
ListPlot[Table[val, 1000]]
```

[image]

it seems unlikely that there is a simple functional relationship between `t` and `p`.

Comment: What if the angles are between 0 and Pi/2 and ```Mod[a-b]<=c<=a+b```?

Comment: Why not try it and report the results?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Please don't change the question after it has received answers.  In this case, the answer you seek is simply derived from the answer given.